# Vim won't open if "execute pathogen#infect()" in .vimrc

Tags: plugin-system

I recently found out about vim-pathogen, and installing vim plugins on my Mac and on remote shared Linux machines has been working great. However, I can't get vim-pathogen working on one remote shared Linux machine I use. I tried using vim-pathogen on an external Linux cluster, but if I have the recommended `execute pathogen#infect()` line in my `.vimrc` file, Vim suddenly won't even open if I clone a plugin repository in my `.vim/bundle` directory. Below is a copy of one of my sessions where I tried to get vim-pathogen working. I had the same problem with other plugins, so it's not just vim-autoclose. How do I go about getting vim-pathogen working? I have Vim 7.0 on this machine.

```
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ ls .vim
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ cat .vimrc
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
> curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ ls .vim/*
.vim/autoload:
pathogen.vim

.vim/bundle:
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ echo -e "execute pathogen#infect()\nsyntax on\nfiletype plugin indent on" > .vimrc
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ cat .vimrc
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ vi
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ git clone https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose .vim/bundle/vim-autoclose
Cloning into '.vim/bundle/vim-autoclose'...
remote: Counting objects: 326, done.
remote: Total 326 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 326 
Receiving objects: 100% (326/326), 97.85 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (132/132), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ ls .vim/*
.vim/autoload:
pathogen.vim

.vim/bundle:
vim-autoclose
lindsb@rrlogin:~$ vi
*** glibc detected *** vim: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000197ee800 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x326da714af]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4b)[0x326da757ab]
vim(clear_tv+0x4e)[0x453c7e]
|      |      |
|      |      |
V      V      V
[ a bunch more lines of similar error output ]
```

Comment: I have a Linux VM I can play with.  Can you comment with a link to the instructions you've been following?  Also, which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Please use a newer vim. This looks like a bug and most likely this has been fixed

Comment: @Wildcard Here's my Linux distribution (not sure how much info you need):lindsb@rrlogin:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-noarchDistributor ID: ScientificSL
Description:    Scientific Linux SL release 5.5 (Boron)
Release:    5.5
Codename:   Boron

lindsb@rrlogin:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-371.8.1.el5 (mockbuild@norob.fnal.gov) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)) #1 SMP Thu Apr 24 14:03:58 CDT 2014

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I don't have root access on this machine. I might consider a local installation of vim if that's not too difficult and there's no other way around it.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I installed the latest version of vim locally, and the bug is gone. However, the local version of vim takes about 1 second to open whereas the global installation opened practically instantaneously. Any idea why that is or how to get around that?

Comment: @user2680824 User `--startuptime` argument to profile startup of vim.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Cool functionality. Looks like "setup clipboard" is responsible for about 90% of that long startup time. My global vim doesn't appear to have the --statuptime option, so I can't compare the two. Is setup clipboard necessary, and if not, can I tel vim not to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Christian Brabandt suggested, my issue was caused by an old version of vim. I installed locally by cloning the [vim git repo](https://github.com/vim/vim.git) then executing `./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr/vim && make && make install` within the top directory of the vim repo. (`$HOME/usr/vim` is where I wanted vim installed) The new vim worked great with the pathogen plugin installation method, but it opened really slowly. By analyzing the startup time with `vim --startuptime out.log` I found that setting up the clipboard was taking up most of the startup time. Following the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635295/vim-takes-a-very-long-time-to-start-up) I found that `vim -X` opened much faster, so I added `set clipboard=exclude:.*` to my `.vimrc` file. Now everything works great.